# Can an assert statement test a redirect from a function?

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I have a function named `def check_if_user_already_exists():` .

Once I use `def check_if_user_already_exists():` in `def test_function()` I want to use an assert statement `assert check_if_user_already_exists() == loginroute`

.

Is this possible?

Another possibility is  I could just change redirect to False. But that seems cumbersome.

Here is the pseudo code that I am describing.

routes.py

```
def check_if_user_already_exists(): 
    # code, redirects to the register route if a user already exists
```

test_functions.py

```
# import check_if_user_already_exists()
def test_function():
    assert check_if_user_already_exists() == redirect to register route
```

Thanks

Comment: Does `check_if_user_already_exists()` return a value? If not, then comparing `check_if_user_already_exists() == loginroute` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I may be able to pass value then assert for the value. Here is an irrelevant example, 
`def redirect_value(): 
    return redirect(url_for('request_reset_password',value='redirect to login'))  
`

Comment: Please [edit] your question so you can format the code.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing `check_if_user_already_exists() == loginroute` only makes sense if `check_if_user_already_exists()` returns a value that the same as the value of the name `loginroute`. I expect that this isn't the case.

Instead, you need to assert on the result of the function. I can think of two options:

1. Learn if flask has a mechanism to query the result of a redirect. If so, use that.
2. Patch the redirect functionality in flask and assert that it was called in the way you expect.

---

On a side note, you have a single function that is performing two separate tasks: 1. validating the state of the application and 2. redirecting to a different route if the validation fails. This violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). I recommend splitting this functionality into two separate functions. One which validates the state of the app and returns a boolean or throws an exception. Another function which calls that first function and then decides what to do based on the result.